# Leitura de tokens em loop infinito

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sintaxe, analise-léxica

Tenho um código que faz leitura de *tokens* de um texto. Estou utilizando o Visual Studio 2013 em um projeto de extensibilidade.

Ao ler o texto através do *scanner* e coletar os *tokens*, o programa entra em um loop infinito:

```
public class TestScanner : IScanner
{
    private TestSource m_source;
    private int m_offset;

    public TestScanner(LanguageService service, IVsTextLines buffer)
    {
        this.m_source = new TestSource(service, buffer, new TestColorizer(service, buffer, this));
    }

    public bool ScanTokenAndProvideInfoAboutIt(TokenInfo tokenInfo, ref int state)
    {
        bool bFound = false;
        if (tokenInfo != null)
        {
            bFound = this.m_source.GetNextToken(m_offset, tokenInfo, ref state);
            if (bFound)
            {
                m_offset = tokenInfo.EndIndex + 1;
            }
        }
        return bFound;
    }

    public void SetSource(string source, int offset)
    {
        m_source.SetText(source);
        m_offset = offset;
    }
}
```

Usei de base este link para verificar a utilidade da interface:

> [IScanner.ScanTokenAndProvideInfoAboutIt Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.iscanner.scantokenandprovideinfoaboutit.aspx)
>
> *Returns true if a token was parsed from the current line and
>   information returned; otherwise, returns false indicating no more
>   tokens on the current line.*

Não estou utilizando a classe diretamente no código, eu implemento a interface através da classe `TestScanner` e o VS a utiliza para ler o código (embora eu tenha a `Colorizer`, porém sem nenhum *override*).

## O que eu espero que aconteça:

- `SetSource` me envie as linhas de código do texto, eu reconheça os tokens e, quando não houver mais, pular para próxima linha, como diz na documentação, basta retornar falso em `ScanTokenAndProvideInfoAboutIt`.

## O que acontece

- De fato, `ScanTokenAndProvideInfoAboutIt` retorna true na primeira vez, e o valor de `m_offset` é modificado, ao passar pela segunda vez no método, m_offset tem o valor do final da linha (13 especificamente, utilizando a string "`using System;`")
- Como `m_offset` é igual ou maior que a string this.m_source.GetNextToken retorna falso, sequencialmente em `ScanTokenAndProvideInfoAboutIt`, ou seja, indico que terminei a coleta e reconhecimento dos tokens.
- Porém `SetSource` me envia novamente a mesma string que realizei a última coleta dos tokens, entrando assim em um loop infinito.

---

Gostaria de saber por que `SetSource` repete a chamada com o mesmo argumento (mesma linha), mesmo eu retornado false. Seria algum bug do Visual Studio?

Que lógica eu preciso utilizar para dizer que acabei de reconhecer os Tokens da linha?

Obs: Se precisar de mais código é só comentar!

Comment: Por algum motivo isso me lembra o `strtok()` do C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acabei encontrando a fonte do loop infinito.

```
m_source.SetText(source);
```

Isto gera uma futura chamada ao próprio parser `TestScanner`, não era uma chamada diretamente recursiva, o que dificultava ainda mais a localização.